# Can anyone help to print hello world? With using basic instructions only here what I did

Tags: mips

Here is what I have:

```
.data

.asciiz "c"

.asciiz "hello world\n"

.globl main

.text 

main:

lui $a0, 0x1002 # set $a0 to start of string

addi $v0, $0, 4 # set command to print

syscall
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a label (e.g, `mylabel:`) to let the assembler know the address of the string you want to print, and then reference it with `la` pseudoinstruction:

```
.data
.asciiz "c"
mylabel:
.asciiz "hello world\n"

.globl main
.text

main:
la $a0, mylabel
addi $v0, $0, 4 # set command to print
syscall
```

Otherwise you should know the location where your string if located.

If you want to know how the assembler translates `la`, you can look at the code generated and translate it again yourself (it should be an `lui` followed by an `ori`). *Mars* simulator lets you see how the `la` is translated.